# Numeric facts database?

Tags: data-request

Is there an online database that contains numeric facts (world population, number of inches in a yard, lbs in a metric ton, ect)?

I'm specifically interested in numeric facts. It can be any subject. The more facts (100s, 1000s, the better)! The more interesting, the better.

Answer (score 3):

I think the highest quality database you can find is wikipedia. Now bear with me for a moment: for every article wikipedia usually provides a very vast set of numeric facts along with the textual facts. The only thing you have to do is to download a wikipedia dump and using the markup language that wikipedia uses, extract the numeric facts.

Comment: +1 Most of these Wikipedia numeric facts are easily queryable remotely using WikiData, which is much more convenient than downloading dumps. See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175896/how-to-get-list-of-statements-for-given-wididata-id

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Numbers API](http://numbersapi.com/). It has some very interesting facts about numbers and even dates. For each request of the form `http://numbersapi.com/49` it returns a random trivia that refers to that number:

> 49 is the number of days and night Siddhartha Gautama spent meditating as a holy man.

[And, of course](http://numbersapi.com/42):

> 42 is the result given by the web search engines Google, Wolfram Alpha and Bing when the query "the answer to life the universe and everything" is entered as a search.

By appending `/date`, `/year`, `/trivia` or `/math` to the number, the specific statements referring to the day of the year (e.g. 4th of July) or the year (e.g. 1492) can be returned.

Answer (score 2):

I don't expect one database to contain population data AND unit conversions (which isn't really "data"). But it sounds like you are looking for what would be found in a World Almanac.

I'd search/browse the [API Dashboard](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis). I didn't find any hits with 'almanac' as a search term, but that would be where I would start.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From what you've described, [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) might be what you're looking for.

They have a no-cost API that allows 2000 'non-commercial' uses per month, but I couldn't find any details on what they consider 'non-commercial' to be.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia's strange affection for lists of factoids sometimes comes very handy. Try by starting with the simple [List of numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numbers) for interesting numbers, constants and peculiar values.

Then continue on [Orders of magnitude (numbers)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_%28numbers%29), which lists some random quantities from demography to mathematics for quantities from 10<sup>-10</sup> to 10<sup>100</sup> (and beyond). Two random picks:

> - Mathematics: The probability of rolling snake eyes 10 times in a row on a pair of fair dice is about 2.74×10<sup>−16</sup>
> - Chess: 4.52×10<sup>46</sup> is a proven upper bound for the number of legal chess positions.

**Bonus:** at the bottom, the info box [Template:Orders of magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aOrders_of_magnitude_wide) links to lists in other articles for "typical values" of many physical quantities like speed (from walking to space crafts), sound pressure (breathing to grenades), ...